# Batch file only works when NOT ran as administrator?

Tags: batch-file, administrator

I have this batch file that when I run it normally(double click it) it runs just fine but when I right click and click "Run as Administrator" it says 'Specified file cannot be found"

I've searched on and about it for 2 days now and no luck. I just don't understand why it works when just normally double clicking it and not as administrator?

Shed some light please.

Comment: If the Batch file run correctly when double click on it, what is the purpose of run it as administrator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When double clicked, the default active directory is the same folder in where the batch file is stored.

When *"Run as administrator"* is used, the default active directory is probably not the same, usually `%systemroot%\system32`.

Without seeing the code this is just an opinion, but if the code in the batch file uses relative paths it is possible that the files it try to use are not found.

Comment: They both seem the open from system32\cmd.exe. At least what the title bar says "C:\Windows\System32\CMD.exe".

Comment: I fixed it, thank you so much. I just added cd "directory" to the top of my batch file. Thanks man appreciate the help!